# A curious thought about inclined planes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

So imagine you have a block on an inclined plane. The angle of inclination is such that the block doesn't move - it is at rest. There's friction and normal force too but the key point is that the block is not moving. Would the angle of inclination (theta max) be larger if the system was on the moon instead of the earth?

or put generally - does the angle of inclination depend on the gravity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the angle of inclination (theta max) be larger if the system was
> on the moon instead of the earth?

If by "theta max" you mean the maximum incline angle where the block will remain at rest (not start to slide), then the answer is no.

The maximum incline angle before sliding is impending is independent of the mass of the object or the force of gravity. This can be shown as follows:

The component of the force of gravity acting down the plane is given by

$$F_{g}=mg\sin\theta$$

The normal force on the plane is $mg\cos\theta$. Thus the maximum possible static friction force acting up the plane is given by

$$F_{s-max}=\mu_{s}mg\cos\theta$$

Where $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction between the block and the incline surface.

Impending sliding of the block is when the two forces are equal

$$mg\sin\theta=\mu_{s}mg\cos\theta$$

$$\mu_{s}=\tan\theta_{max}$$

$$\theta_{max}=\tan^{-1}\mu_{s}$$

So $\theta_{max}$ is independent of the mass and the magnitude of the force of gravity. It depends only on the coefficient of static friction. So the force of gravity, be it $g$ or $\frac{1}{6}g$ (approximate on the moon) is not a factor.

Of course if there were no gravity, the block will not move regardless of the inclination since there is no downward force along the incline nor normal force perpendicular to the incline (i.e., the net force acting on the block is zero).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like since with zero gravity, nothing would fall regardless of the steepness of the slope, and with high enough gravity any amount of friction would start the sliding down-hill.

I would say ýes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The weight on the Moon is less and therefore so are the component of the weight down the slope and at right angles to the slope in the same proportion as that of the decrease in the weight.
The magnitude of the component of weight at right angles to the slope is equal to the magnitude to the normal force.
So the normal force changes in the same proportion as does the frictional force up the slope which is proportional to the normal force.

Thus the magnitudes of component of weight down the slope and the frictional force up the slope are both reduced in the same proportion, so the friction force is still able to hold the block in position as it is the larger force.

Answer (score 0):

g is the only constant that differes in each scenario.  Constants are only useful in determining mathematical quantities.  Therefore, unless the question is asking for the value of the angle, and gives the value for m, the value of g is irrelevant because it has no effect on the value of m, which is the same for both scenarios.  Thus the angle is dependent on the value of m, not the value of g.